# PHP API to retrieve location of the source of an SMS

Tags: php, sms

I'm working on a web platform to retrieve the location from which an SMS was sent from.  I read that Service Providers do not normally send details such as LAC or Cell-ID along with an SMS for security and privacy reasons.

But I really need this for my undergraduate research work. Has anyone ever done this?

I've already achieved the part where the SMS gets forwarded to the web server (using an Android gateway: Telerivet), I just need to be able to filter out the location of the incoming SMS.

I'll really appreciate your input, constructive or destructive.

Thanks.